# Which techniques and detectors are used to measure and develop ultra light energy (under 1 eV)?

Tags: energy, spectroscopy

Some particles properties or some events hve very very low energy like neutrino,
 axions, WIMP..
I wish to understand better how physicists or chemists develop and measure this ultra light energy.
And what are the possible implementations of so small energies in real technologies or material properties ? 
 We talk about *attojoule* so in theory it would be possible to modulate the energy of electron transition levels.
Are there any studies on this?

Answer (score -4):

[Axion Dark Matter Experiment - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion_Dark_Matter_Experiment)

It uses a resonant microwave cavity within a large superconducting magnet to search for cold dark matter axions in the local galactic dark matter halo.

[Pierre Sikivie invented the axion haloscope in 1983](http://Sikivie,%20P.%20(1983).%20%22Experimental%20Tests%20of%20the%20%22Invisible%22%20Axion%22.%20Physical%20Review%20Letters.%2051%20(16):%201415)

---

WIMPs, Axions,... are not particles because they have never been detected.    They are  **'Particles on paper'**

From the link: "its gravitational interactions with familiar matter leave **unmistakable evidence** for its existence" ... "Approximately five times more abundant than ordinary matter,..."

**Unmistakable evidence** : Not so fast... theoretical physicists had no imagination to find a correct model of galactodynamics until now. 
The so called 'Dark matter' is an invented parameter to make the model fit the data. It is not 'data', it is nothing.  Decades looking for 'nothing' is consistent with the results: 'nothing'.
Two facts should make everyone to look for an anternative explanation of galactodynamics:
The [disk galaxies are lopsided](https://www.google.pt/search?q=lopsidedness%20galaxy&oq=galaxylopsidedness%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.23739j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but 'central forces' are symetric .
The **disk galaxies have a vortex like force field**. This is evident when one compares its shape, i.e. the force field, with the ones of the hurricanes and vortexes have not a central force origin.